# GUI Tool to test javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for **GUI/Windows based** tool to test my javascript code there instead of using firebug or other in-browser tool.

I want to play around with javascript language outside of the browser to learn more about it.

Has anyone come across such tool? I could not find one :(

**Edit:** I am looking for GUI/Windows based on which can be used even if I am not connected to **internet** and still play around with javascript.

Comment: There are three very popular ones called IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Are you saying you want to run javascript in a context other than a webpage? Or you just want a different environment for debugging?

Comment: @MatthewNichols: Yes Windows-based one, I want to learn javascript language for the moment forgetting about web at this time.

Comment: you can use any browser if you're not connected to the internet

Comment: So just use your browser to test on a local file. Did you realize you can view javascript on a local machine? It's client side so you don't need a server to run it.

Comment: You can run either V8 or SpiderMonkey from the command line if that's of your liking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).
[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/#javascript,html) is another option.

Comment: I am looking for GUI/Windows based on which can be used even if iam not connected to internet. Thanks

Comment: Oh. You might want to add that to your question.

Comment: It was there on first line :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Web Developer Express is free and has a great JavaScript editor and debugger.

Comment: Does that have a JavaScript interpreter?

Comment: The IE browser is used in conjunction with debugger which of course includes an interpreter as well as an immediate and command window, call stack, and watch list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something that you don't need to be connected to the internet for, why can't you just use your browser? I assume you've already got some kind of development platform now. Save to a local HTML file and view it on your local browser.

Do you not have some kind of a GUI development program like DreamWeaver or CODA or something like that? (I'm on a mac, so I'm not familiar with a lot of windows based programs).